# htacess url rewrite? on a php get system

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I use the code below to basically go to my pages.  How it works is I put `index.php?req=pagename` and it will check my protected folder to see if the file is there if it is then it goes there. I need a mod rewrite so that it doesnt show all that `index.php?req=pagename` and just shows `/pagename`

```
    require_once("protected/header.php");

    if (isset($_GET['req'])) {
        $req = $_GET['req'];
    } else {
        $req = "overall";
    }

    require_once("protected/$req.php");
    require_once("protected/footer.php");
```

Comment: google is your friend: http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite

Answer (score 3):

Your code allows *any* php file (barring safemode/open_basedir restrictions) to be parsed and executed. You need to **escape that input first**, even if it's something as rudimentary as removing slashes, tildes and periods.

As far as rewrite goes, simply create a `.htaccess` file in your document root along the lines of:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?req=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: im a noob i put that in the htacess and it does nothing all pages are still like /index.php?req=pagename like i said what i want is /pagename

Comment: Huh? You're typing `yourdomain/pagename` and it's showing a 404 error?

Comment: Ensure rewrite module is enabled in apache. Place `.htaccess` in correct. Doing those two things (and making sure `/pagename` doesn't exist of course) will yield the correct results. Please checkmark this answer when you are able :)

Answer (score -2):

You will have to use POST instead of GET if you want a clean dynamic url.  Your question though doesn't make much sense.

Comment: He wants to rewrite `/pagename` to `index.php?req=pagename`.